# Search the latest Build Number in all defined artifactory repository for Job

Tags: java, groovy, artifactory

I am able to find the latest build number with the below groovy code but now my requirement is bit changed. Currently I am trying to find the latest build number in just only libs-snaphot-local artifactory repository but now I want to search the latest build number in three more repositories for the same job name instead of only libs-snapshot-local

Three extra repositories are libs-alpha-local, libs-stage-local and libs-release-local. So code should be like that it will search the latest build number in all four artifactory repository for e.g.

```
libs-snapshot-local is having build number    3,2 
libs-alpha-local is having build number       8,4 
libs-stage-local is having build number       5,6 
libs-release-local is having build number     9,1

so the latest build number would be 9
```

Below is my code which is searching only in one repository

```
import groovy.json.*
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def applicationLatestBuild = getLatestBuild('application')
def DiscoveryProductsLatestBuild = getLatestBuild('DiscoveryProduct')

//String[] testArray = ["libs-snapshot-local", "libs-alpha-local", "libs-stage-local", "libs-release-local"]

def thr= Thread.currentThread().executable

def getLatestBuild( jobName ) {
  def searchUrl = "http://xyz.test.com:9090/api/search/artifact?name=${jobName}&repos=libs-snapshot-local"
  def conn = searchUrl.toURL().openConnection()
  conn.setRequestProperty("X-Result-Detail", "info, properties")
  def searchResultTxt = conn.content.text
  //println "Found: ${searchResultTxt}"
  def searchResults = new JsonSlurper().parseText(searchResultTxt)
  def builds = searchResults.results.findAll{it.properties["build.number"] != null}.collect { Integer.parseInt(it.properties["build.number"][0]) }.sort().unique().reverse()
  builds[0]
}

def pa = new ParametersAction([
new StringParameterValue("applicationLatestBuild", "${applicationLatestBuild}"),
  new StringParameterValue("DiscoveryProductsLatestBuild", "${DiscoveryProductsLatestBuild}"),
])


// add variable to current job
thr.addAction(pa)
println (applicationLatestBuild)
println(DiscoveryProductsLatestBuild)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the answer

You need to add other repositories here in this line and it will give your the desired results.

def searchUrl = "http://xyz.test.com:9090/api/search/artifact?name=${jobName}&repos=libs-snapshot-local,libs-alpha-local,libs-stage-local,libs-release-local"

```
import groovy.json.*
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def applicationLatestBuild = getLatestBuild('application')
def DiscoveryProductsLatestBuild = getLatestBuild('DiscoveryProduct')

//String[] testArray = ["libs-snapshot-local", "libs-alpha-local", "libs-stage-local", "libs-release-local"]

def thr= Thread.currentThread().executable

def getLatestBuild( jobName ) {
  def searchUrl = "http://xyz.test.com:9090/api/search/artifact?name=${jobName}&repos=libs-snapshot-local,libs-alpha-local,libs-stage-local,libs-release-local"
  def conn = searchUrl.toURL().openConnection()
  conn.setRequestProperty("X-Result-Detail", "info, properties")
  def searchResultTxt = conn.content.text
  //println "Found: ${searchResultTxt}"
  def searchResults = new JsonSlurper().parseText(searchResultTxt)
  def builds = searchResults.results.findAll{it.properties["build.number"] != null}.collect { Integer.parseInt(it.properties["build.number"][0]) }.sort().unique().reverse()
  builds[0]
}

def pa = new ParametersAction([
new StringParameterValue("applicationLatestBuild", "${applicationLatestBuild}"),
  new StringParameterValue("DiscoveryProductsLatestBuild", "${DiscoveryProductsLatestBuild}"),
])


// add variable to current job
thr.addAction(pa)
println (applicationLatestBuild)
println(DiscoveryProductsLatestBuild)
```